# Convert oracle script to mysql script

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, syntax, sql-insert

Need help on this I am migrating the database from oracle to mysql. I am running the below query in oracle it works fine but in mysql getting

```
INSERT INTO xyz(rid, pid)
SELECT rid, pid
  FROM ((SELECT distinct rd, 
              (SELECT p.pid FROM abc p WHERE p.permission='jury') AS pid
          FROM xyz
         WHERE pid IN (SELECT p.pid
                         FROM abc p
                        WHERE p.permission in ('jury'))
       ));
```

Getting the below error

```
Every derived table must have its own alias [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=1248]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a MySQL user, but googling the error shows that it's expecting the inline view to have an alias:

```
insert into xyz (rid, pid)
  select rid, pid
  from   ( (select distinct rd,
                            (select p.pid
                             from   abc p
                             where  p.permission = 'jury')
                              as pid
            from   xyz
            where  pid in (select p.pid
                           from   abc p
                           where  p.permission in ('jury')))) res;
```

However, isn't this just a really, really overly complicated way of doing:

```
insert into xyz (rid, pid)                         
select distinct xyz.rd,
                abc.pid
from   xyz
       inner join abc on (xyz.pid = abc.pid and abc.permission = 'jury');
```

?